# MySQL. Logical error in function that should return string with spaces before capital letters

Tags: mysql, sql, string, function, string-concatenation

I tried recreating an SQL server function on MySQL. The function should be able to return a string with spaces before capital letters. For example, writing "HelloWorld" would return "Hello World".

Other Examples:

"IanLikesJane" -> "Ian Likes Jane"

"CodLiverOil" -> "Cod Liver Oil"

My logic is as follows

```
result string = ''
Foreach character in input string:

  If this letter is capital:
    If the preceding or next letter is not capital:
      If the the preceding and current letter is not a space:
        Concatinate space after result string

Concatinate this letter with result
```

MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION SpaceBeforeCapital (str NVARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(8000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT; 
DECLARE j INT;
DECLARE cp NCHAR;
DECLARE c0 NCHAR;
DECLARE c1 NCHAR;
DECLARE result NVARCHAR(8000);

SET i = 1;
SET j =  CHAR_LENGTH(str);
SET result = '';    

WHILE (i <= j) DO       
   SET cp = SUBSTRING(str,(i-1),1);
   SET c0 = SUBSTRING(str,i,1);
   SET c1 = SUBSTRING(str,(i+1),1);

   -- IF c0 = UPPER(c0) THEN
   -- IF c0 = UPPER(CONVERT(c0 USING latin1)) AND (cp != UPPER(CONVERT(cp USING latin1)) OR c1 != UPPER(CONVERT(c1 USING latin1))) 
    IF c0 = UPPER(CONVERT(c0 USING latin1)) THEN
        IF cp != UPPER(CONVERT(cp USING latin1)) OR c1 != UPPER(CONVERT(c1 USING latin1)) THEN
            IF cp != ' ' AND c0 != ' ' THEN
                SET result = CONCAT(result,' ');
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
   -- END IF; 

   SET result = CONCAT(result,c0);
   SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

RETURN result;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

My script is pretty much doing the opposite the input strings without any spaces. Anyone got a fix?

Comment: Can you edit your post and at the bottom, show a sample string of what is expected as the inbound parameter and what you are trying to get out of it...  Your verbiage describing doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: As I said, the input string "HelloWorld" should return "Hello World" (space before the capital letter). Similar examples include:

"IanLikesJane" -> "Ian Likes Jane"
"CodLiverOil" -> "Cod Liver Oil"

Comment: Sorry, my bad on missing Hello World sample... eyes still focusing this morning :)

Comment: No worries, the function doesn't return any errors, but it doesn't behave the way it should either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that the problem here is that [case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) is not working as you'd like.

Try replacing `UPPER` with `BINARY UPPER` to force case sensitivity. Hence:

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE FUNCTION SpaceBeforeCapital (str NVARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(8000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT; 
DECLARE j INT;
DECLARE cp NCHAR;
DECLARE c0 NCHAR;
DECLARE c1 NCHAR;
DECLARE result NVARCHAR(8000);

SET i = 1;
SET j =  CHAR_LENGTH(str);
SET result = '';    

WHILE (i <= j) DO       
   SET cp = SUBSTRING(str,(i-1),1);
   SET c0 = SUBSTRING(str,i,1);
   SET c1 = SUBSTRING(str,(i+1),1);

   -- IF c0 = UPPER(c0) THEN
   -- IF c0 = UPPER(CONVERT(c0 USING latin1)) AND (cp != UPPER(CONVERT(cp USING latin1)) OR c1 != UPPER(CONVERT(c1 USING latin1))) 
    IF c0 = BINARY UPPER(CONVERT(c0 USING latin1)) THEN
        IF cp != BINARY UPPER(CONVERT(cp USING latin1)) OR c1 != BINARY UPPER(CONVERT(c1 USING latin1)) THEN
            IF cp != ' ' AND c0 != ' ' THEN
                SET result = CONCAT(result,' ');
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
   -- END IF; 

   SET result = CONCAT(result,c0);
   SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

RETURN result;
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Scratch that, it worked :). I removed the Convert also and kept the character on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If still no luck from others, I have the following two suggestions... Try just using UPPER() without convert / Latin1... as you already have a single character to deal with.

```
IF c0 = UPPER(c0) THEN
```

same with rest of upper() conversion tests

If that does not work, I would then build a string at the beginning of your function such as

```
DECLARE AllUpper NVARCHAR(26);
SET AllUpper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

then use INSTR()  to see if the character is in the all upper string

```
   IF INSTR( AllUpper, c0 ) > 0
```

similar with upper conversion tests